# Add HTML after spans which text is greater than

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have part of HTML:

```html
<div class="product">
  <h1>Product 1</h1>
  <img src="">
  <span class="price">435</span>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <h1>Product 2</h1>
  <img src="">
  <span class="price">599</span>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <h1>Product 3</h1>
  <img src="">
  <span class="price">850</span>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <h1>Product 4</h1>
  <img src="">
  <span class="price">239</span>
</div>
```

I want to add `<p>Free shipping</p>` after `<span class="price">` to products which price is greater than 400.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear in your requirement? Generally these type of questions would get downvoted in SO

Comment: Explain more about your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)  API of jquery .And use `parseFloat()` to convert string to `Number`

```js
$('span.price').each(function(){
   if(parseFloat($(this).text()) > 400)
  $(this).after().append('<p>Free shipping</p>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
    <h1>Product 1</h1>
    <img src="">
    <span class="price">435</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
    <h1>Product 2</h1>
    <img src="">
    <span class="price">599</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
    <h1>Product 3</h1>
    <img src="">
    <span class="price">850</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
    <h1>Product 4</h1>
    <img src="">
    <span class="price">239</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```js
$('.price').each(function(){
  if($(this).text() > 400)
    $(this).after('<p>Free shipping</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <h1>Product 1</h1>
  <img src="">
  <span class="price">435</span>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <h1>Product 2</h1>
  <img src="">
  <span class="price">599</span>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <h1>Product 3</h1>
  <img src="">
  <span class="price">850</span>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <h1>Product 4</h1>
  <img src="">
  <span class="price">239</span>
</div>
```

You can also achieve that in vanilla JS

```js
var allPrice = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.price'));
allPrice.forEach(function(el){
  if(el.textContent > 400){
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = 'Free shipping';
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(p, el.nextSibling);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <h1>Product 1</h1>
  <img src="">
  <span class="price">435</span>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <h1>Product 2</h1>
  <img src="">
  <span class="price">599</span>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <h1>Product 3</h1>
  <img src="">
  <span class="price">850</span>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <h1>Product 4</h1>
  <img src="">
  <span class="price">239</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need a library of 87KB to do something that's built in in JavaScript?

Comment: @Roy, I was thinking about the simplicity as the library is tagged in the question. Now added the solution in vanilla JS as well. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Select all the spans with document.querySelectorAll and in a loop check if the price is >400 append free shipping to it

```js
var a=document.querySelectorAll('.product > .price')
a.forEach(e=>+e.textContent>=400?e.textContent+="  Free Shipping":false)
```

```html
<div class="product">
    <h1>Product 1</h1>
    <img src="">
    <span class="price">435</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
    <h1>Product 2</h1>
    <img src="">
    <span class="price">599</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
    <h1>Product 3</h1>
    <img src="">
    <span class="price">850</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
    <h1>Product 4</h1>
    <img src="">
    <span class="price">239</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `.filter()`

```js
$('span.price').filter(function(){
  return parseInt($(this).text()) > 400;
}).after('<p>Free shipping</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <h1>Product 1</h1>
  <img src="">
  <span class="price">435</span>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <h1>Product 2</h1>
  <img src="">
  <span class="price">599</span>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <h1>Product 3</h1>
  <img src="">
  <span class="price">850</span>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <h1>Product 4</h1>
  <img src="">
  <span class="price">239</span>
</div>
```